# Eve + MongoDB with special characters

Tags: python, mongodb, shell, urlencode, eve

I have a (Mongo) database with locations from multiple planets/moons/asteroids.
My db is called `nomenclature` and the collection is `centroids`.
Here is a sample of the documents in this collection:

```
[
{
  "name":"kachina chasmata",
  "location":{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[-116.65,-32.6]
  },
  "body":"ariel"
},
{
  "name":"hokusai",
  "location":{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[16.65,57.84]
  },
  "body":"mercury"
},
{
  "name":"cañas",
  "location":{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[89.86,-31.188]
  },
  "body":"mars"
},
{
  "name":"anseris cavus",
  "location":{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[95.5,-29.708]
  },
  "body":"mars"
}
]
```

Such db/collection will receive queries on its `body` and `name` fields.

*You may have noticed the whitespaces and special characters* ("`ñ`") *in* (`name`) *some documents.* That is precisely where my question is.

I am using [eve](https://github.com/pyeve/eve) to publish this db/collection through a read-only (`GET`) interface.
With the following `DOMAIN` in the settings,

```
DOMAIN = {
    'centroids': {
        'item_title': 'crater centroid',
        'url': 'centroid/<regex("[\w]+"):body>/<regex("[\w ]+"):name>'
    }
}
```

, Eve answers just fine to a request like:

```sh
$ curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/centroid/mercury/hokusai'
```

or,

```sh
$ curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/centroid/mars/anseris%20cavus'
```

when there is whitespace in `name` (notice the whitespace in the settings for *name* `<regex("[\w ]+"):name>`).

The question is: how should I handle special characters -- like `ñ` -- in such environment? Who should handle encoding/decoding: the user, the interface (Eve) or the database (MongoDB)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it. I figured it out when I tested the app through the browser, where everything works fine. I'll keep this question here and add the answer here 'cause may be useful to somebody; I learned and hopefully others will too.

**TL;DR:** the *client* is the responsible to *encode* the query, and then *decode* the result if necessary.

After my first tests using the command-line I did it through my web browser, where the url `http://localhost:5000/centroid/mars/cañas` has no problem in being accepted by the app/db (Eve/MongoDB) and give back the answer:

```xml
<resource>
  <resource>
    <body>mars</body>
    <lat>-31.188</lat>
    <lon>89.86</lon>
    <name>cañas</name>
  </resource>
</resource>
```

Great. But now I wanted to know how to do that from the terminal/bash.

First I googled for "url encode" and there was this little lice tool to play with: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/. Which encoded `cañas` for me (it uses Javascript [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)), and now I could try with `curl`:

```sh
$ curl -s 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/centroid/mars/ca%C3%B1as%0A' | json_pp
{
   "_items" : [
      {
         "lat" : -31.188,
         "body" : "mars",
         "lon" : 89.86,
         "name" : "ca�as"
      }
   ]
}
```

Good. The answer is in `ISO-8859`.

*Then* I wanted to do the encoding myself, in my terminal.
A second search, now for "encode utf8 bash" brought me to this post: https://www.tecmint.com/convert-files-to-utf-8-encoding-in-linux/, where I learned about the `iconv` tool.

Using `iconv` I had a different encoded string -- I did `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1` --, but everything worked just fine:

```sh
$ echo 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/centroid/mars/cañas' | file -
/dev/stdin: UTF-8 Unicode text
$ URL=$(echo 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/centroid/mars/cañas' | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 -)
$ echo $URL
http://127.0.0.1:5000/centroid/mars/ca�as
$ echo $URL | file -
/dev/stdin: ISO-8859 text
$ curl -s $URL | json_pp
{
   "_items" : [
      {
         "lat" : -31.188,
         "lon" : 89.86,
         "body" : "mars",
         "name" : "ca�as"
      }
   ]
}
```